# Install themes on kubuntu

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, themes, kde

I just installed the package kubuntu-desktop and i found some really good themes online:

http://kubuntu-art.org/content/show.php/Ice+cream+Theme+%28QtCurve%2CEmerald%2CChrome%29?content=151493

http://kubuntu-art.org/content/show.php/Elementary+for+KDE+%28QTCurve+%2B+Emerald%29?content=152404

can anybody tell me how to install those themes on (k)ubuntu 12.04 ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

**Window decorations**

The appearance of window borders, titlebars and buttons.

You will need an engine and a theme.

**KDE Style**

The elements of a graphical user interface, such as buttons, scrollbars, tabs, and menus.

You will need an engine and a theme.

**In this case - QtCurve,Emerald**

The QtCurve is in the official Ubuntu repositories. The QtCurve engine can be installed with the package: qtcurve

> Description: Unified window decoration for KDE and GTK+ (meta-package)
>   This package installs all packages related with QtCurve:   *
>   kde-style-qtcurve   * kwin-style-qtcurve   * gtk2-engines-qtcurve   *
>   qtcurve-i18n  .  QtCurve is a set of widget styles for KDE and GTK+.
>   It provides a consistent  look between KDE and GTK+ applications,
>   which is easy on the eyes and visually  pleasing. Homepage:
>   http://www.kde-look.org/content/show.php?content=40492

The Smaragd (Emerald for KDE): http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/?content=125162

> Description: Smaragd is a window decoration engine for the KDE window
>   manager KWin. It allows you to use Emerald theme files (from
>   Compiz/Beryl) with KDE SC 4.

The Smaragd can be found from the PPA repositories: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=smaragd

Download the deb and install it.

[image]

**Ice cream Theme**

Download - unpack the tar package.

Extract the Ice cream QtCurve.emerald to the $HOME/.emerald/theme.

KDE System Settings > Workspace Appearance > Window Decorations > Smaragd

[image]

KDE System Settings > Application Appearance > Style > Widget style: QtCurve -> Configure -> Import QtCurve Settings File

[image]

Comment: Quality answer +1

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>  . Type as themes in the search box . Then you will option of Desktop Themes  and select it open .

[image]

Then you will get a window , and in that window at bottom boarder you will get an option like "get new themes "

[image]

Then it will open an window for you and there at search option you can search your theme .

[image]